# Do lucky numbers contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions?

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions, distribution-of-primes

The [lucky numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number)
are defined by a sieve, which results in numbers that 
asymptotically mirror the prime density $\sim n / \log n$:
$$
1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 21, 25, 31, 33, 37, 43, 49, 51, 63, 67, 69, 73, 75, 79, 87, 93, 99, \ldots
$$
[OEIS A000959](https://oeis.org/A000959).

The [Green-Tao Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) established that
the primes contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions.

> ***Q***. Do the lucky numbers contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions?

Comment: Answered on MO: ["likely impossible"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359674/6094) to avoid arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions.